# Splitting and Running a code in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I am currently working on a project where people write articles, which are stored in a database. The credit for the article is stored as `[USER ID]:Role` and then loaded into the page by loading the user information from another table using the USER ID then implementing the role into the credit.

For example: `1:Writing` would produce `Brad - Writing`

But as there are multiple credits per page they will be stored in the same column separated by a comma. For example: `1:Writing,4:Images,8:Music` which would then appear as

```
Brad - Writing
Ben - Images
Jay - Music
```

To do this I am exploding the contents of the column with the separator `,` and then running a `foreach();` on the array.

In this `foreach();` I need to look up the ID's of the users then load the information from the table and then include the Role as well in the credit.

I can't think of the best way to do this. Would I need to run a `preg_replace` to run a separate function to get the information or would there be another way to do it? Or would there even be a better way to store the information in the database?

Thanks in advance, Brad.

Comment: the best way would be to use regular many-to-many relationship database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in MySQL in a separate table

```
article_id   user_id   role
---------------------------
Brad       | 1       | Writing
```

and then issue a query like this

```
SELECT u.name, ac.role FROM article_credits ac 
    LEFT JOIN users u ON ac.user_id = u.id
    WHERE ac.article_id = ?
```

Or you can extract it from your current field using `preg_match` to catch all `user_id`s and feed them to

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id IN (' . implode(',', $user_ids).')'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do all the things you are doing but don't run query to load information from table in foreach loop instead you can use:

```
 $query = "Select * from table where id in ('" . implode("','", $columns) . "')";
```

then execute query